# How do you get the domain name of a forwarded URL in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I'm hosting my website at `web_app.herokuapp.com`. I'm having 2 custom domains `testone.com` and `testtwo.com` point their DNS to `web_app.herokuapp.com`. But when I go to `testone.com` or `testtwo.com` `request.host` in my web application it is giving me `web_app` and not `testone` or `testtwo`. Is it possible to get the endpoint domain URLs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP header is available:

```
request.headers['X-forwarded-for']
```